# how to make a EditText field in own android-auto APP

Tags: java, android, android-auto

I try to make a form in android auto what the user can input text in a field but the android auto soft keyboard not pop up when focus

Comment: What kind of app are you building? Media, messaging, parking, etc...? This is not possible in most Android Auto apps, but it could depend on the app type.

Comment: messaging! 
but I can change

Comment: This page has everything you need to know about messaging in Android Auto: https://developer.android.com/training/cars/messaging The short of it is that you don't create a UI for messaging or media app types. They build the UI and you use a service to provide your information to it. Typing on a keyboard is fundamentally dangerous while driving, so your users must interact with voice. Look at the Message Flow section for specifics: https://developer.android.com/training/cars/messaging#workflow